Do we need a "Set-Information" tag as well as "Sets"?
Questions about specific sets seem to make sense with with the sets, while questions asking about the details that would justify a set-information tag (e.g. weight/number of bricks/etc.) seem almost off topic for this site† - there are other sites (BrickLink/BrickSet) that do a better job of that, and (as proved by the answers provided to this question).
I'm not sure that the rebuilding question should be tagged set-information either.
† I came to this conclusion after thinking about it after I'd answered it. I'd flag it as off topic myself, but my vote is binding, so will wait to see what others think.

sets and set-information are now synonymous with one another. Questions like "How much does the Luke's Landspeeder (8092) weigh?" ask a very specific question but the answer given applies to any given set. A question asking how much X set weighs would be closed as a duplicate of that question.
"Why are there extra pieces in my set?" is a good example of a question referring to sets in general. It doesn't address a particular set in the title. There are however questions that need to be specific like this one.
